How to Align text in the center and buttons at the bottom within a Surface taking 80% screen height inside a LazyColumn?
This is my CardItem
    @Composable
fun QuotesFullCardItem(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, quotesDataItem: QuotesDataItem) {
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight(0.8f),
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)
    ) {

        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                alignment = Alignment.TopCenter,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.pic),
                contentDescription = null
            )
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            ) {
                Text(text = quotesDataItem.quote ?: "No Quote")
                Text(text = quotesDataItem.author ?: "Unknown Author")
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(bottom = 8.dp),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom
                ) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Share, contentDescription = null)
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Home, contentDescription = null)
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Phone, contentDescription = null)
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.AccountCircle, contentDescription = null)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This is my home screen
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val viewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val quotes by viewModel.quotes

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.fetchQuotes()
    }

    Surface(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding()
    )
    {
        when (val result = quotes) {
            is Result.Loading -> {

            }

            is Result.Success -> {
                QuotesListScreen(quotes = result.data.orEmpty())
            }

            is Result.Error -> {
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun QuotesListScreen(quotes: List<QuotesDataItem?>) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
    ) {
        items(quotes.size) { index ->
            quotes[index]?.let { quote ->
                QuotesFullCardItem(quotesDataItem = quote)
            }
        }
    }

}

Hello folks , I want to show text in the middle of the card, buttons in the bottom of the card.I want this card takes only 80 percent of the screen height .. but the problem is it doesnt takes 80 percent height and text is shown in top and buttons is also shown below the text. I use this card inside LazyColumn.
